# How to trigger multiple filters based on multiple conditional statements in VBA Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A14") = True Then _
   Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= "Option1"

If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A15") = True Then _
   Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= "Option2"

If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A16") = True Then _
   Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= "Option3"

If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A17") = True Then _
   Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= "Option4"
```

Let's say in Sheet1 of Excel, there are 4 Check boxes(Form Control) having some names such as Metric1, Metric2, Metric3 and Metric4.

There are 4 cells in the same sheet let's say A14, A15, A16 and A17 that are associated with the above Check boxes using macro such that Metric1 <-> A14, Metric2 <-> A15, Metric3 <-> A16 and Metric4 <-> A17.

Now if one selects one or more check boxes, the corresponding cells will show TRUE and if the checkbox is unchecked then it will display FALSE.

There is a second sheet Sheet2 and there is a column of Metrics having all the 4 values i.e. Metric1, Metric2, Metric3 and Metric4 respectively. Let's say I have selected check boxes for Metric 1 and Metric 4 in Sheet1. This will change cells A14 and A17 to TRUE. Now, based on those cells that are TRUE, I want to see only Metric 1 and Metric 4 filtered in the Metric column.

How can I write a VBA code for this problem? Please help.

I tried using multiple IF conditions, but the problem is, the filter takes the value of the last If condition.

Comment: Which parts of your problem are working and which parts are not?

Comment: The last part wherein based on cells that are TRUE (if the check box is selected) the field called Metric should get filtered showing only those metrics for which the cells display TRUE

Comment: In Sheet1 we have the Check boxes(Form control) and associated cells A14:A17 . In Sheet2 we have Metrics Column(field)

Comment: Edit your code to the question please-

Comment: I am new to VBA, so please don't down vote my query. I will be extremely grateful to anyone who could suggest how to tackle this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Click on EDIT directly below your post and paste the code into there then highlight the code and click the curly brackets icon to define it as a code block. You can paste more code in there than in comments here.

Answer (score 0):

`AutoFilter` accepts `Array` for filtering multiple values at the same time. For example (not tested) :

```
arr = Array( IIf([Sheet1!A14], "Option1", ""), IIf([Sheet1!A15], "Option2", ""), _
             IIf([Sheet1!A16], "Option3", ""), IIf([Sheet1!A17], "Option4", ""))

[Sheet2!A:A].AutoFilter 1, arr, xlFilterValues
```

Comment: I just edited the last part a bit and voila ! 
 it works :) Thanks a million! Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues